# Expected Identifier in Public Class

Tags: asp-classic

I'm getting the following error on my site;

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f2'

Expected identifier

/includes/pagecontent.asp, line 2

Public Class Article
-------^
```

The above include is referenced in my page as follows;

```
<%
    Dim article : Set article = GetArticle(22)
%>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/pagecontent.asp" -->

<h1><%=article.Title%></h1>
<div><%=article.Content%></div>
```

I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me resolve this one? I've read a few posts about changing virtual to file, but this is not useful for me in my site structure.

The pagecontent.asp looks like this;

```
Public Class Article
    public ID
    public Title
    public Content
End Class

Function GetArticle(article)

    Dim conn: Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 
    conn.Open Application("database") 

    Dim cmd: Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.command") 
    Dim rsArticle
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    cmd.CommandText = "prc_getArticle" 
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ArticleID", adInteger, adParamInput,, article) 
    Dim rsArticle: Set rsArticle = cmd.Execute 

    IF Not rsArticle.EOF Then
       Set GetArticle = new Article;

       GetArticle.ID = rsArticle.fields("art_id") 
       GetArticle.Title  = rsArticle.fields("art_title") 
       GetArticle.Content  = rsArticle.fields("art_content")  
    Else
       Set GetArticle = Nothing
    End If

    rsArticle.Close() 
End Function
```

Comment: Is that your entire pagecontent.asp, or have you removed the <% %> at start and end of the file?

Comment: I removed the <% %> as I thought I maybe had to for posting here?

Comment: OK.  In your master file, you don't have option explicit or the like after the include statement?

Comment: Hey Paul. Just updated the post to show the full content of the .asp page where the include is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little while since I've done ASP, but try the following, it might work or throw more light on the error:

```
<%Option Explicit%>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/pagecontent.asp" --> 
<% 
    Dim article : Set article = GetArticle(22) 
%> 

<h1><%=article.Title%></h1> 
<div><%=article.Content%></div>
```

I think the error is a false report, with the Dim article line causing the problem, but the error reported is falling into the include statement.

Comment: Hey Paul. Looks like you're right. Made the changes you described and I now get the following error;

<pre><code>Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0411'
Name redefined

/includes/pagecontent.asp, line 19

Dim rsArticle: Set rsArticle = cmd.Execute
----^</code></pre>

Comment: That's because you have a `Dim rsArticle` near the top of your function, and then a `Dim rsArticle: ...` farther in.  Remove one or the other.

Comment: @cHao - Removed the Dim rsArticle on line 14 of pagecontent.asp. But now get; Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0411'

Name redefined

/delivery/index.asp, line 6

Dim article : Set article = GetArticle(22)
----^

Comment: @Neil Bradley: VBScript is not case sensitive.  Meaning it might be getting confused about 'article' (the variable) vs 'Article' (the type name).  I haven't worked with VBScript in ages, so i don't remember whether types and variables and functions etc have different namespaces, but it seems likely that they don't.

Comment: @cHao - You were right. Changed all references of 'article' to 'myarticle'. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In VBScript, classes don't have the "Public" keyword -- that's used for declaring variables inside a class, but classes themselves are implicitly public, and can't be declared with an access modifier.

Comment: +1, but it would be more accurate to say that a class in VBScript cannot ever be declared public (or private for that matter). You can declare variables, properties, functions and subprocedures for public/private, but not classes.